# Separate mirror

Tags: mirror

I am currently building a human body.

I already finish it using *Mirror modifier*, now I need to place hands in another position but they are the same object.

I need to separate to have two objects.

Comment: you mean you need the left hand to have another position than the right hand? In that case apply the modifier (put your mouse on the modifier and ctrl A)

Comment: what do you mean when you say that they are the same object? If you've applied the modifier, you should be able to move the left part without moving the right part, so maybe you haven't applied the Mirror, or you've enabled the mirror option (on the top right of the 3D view)

Comment: Thanks it worked, it was obvious, i am beginner.